# How to make prettier recognise double curly brackets as JavaScript in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, abstract-syntax-tree, eslint, prettier

I use VS Code editor with `prettier` to format my code, but in Google Tag Manager, you wrap variables with double curly brackets around it. E.g to define a variable in Google Tag Manager, you do

```
{{my_own_variable}}
```

This causes issues with `prettier` as it's not valid JavaScript code. What can I do to make `prettier` simply see this as a variable? I am willing to write a plugin for this (if possible) or is there some kind of config I can use etc. Any help would be appreciated

Edit: I want to make `prettier` accept and format the file, just like normal JavaScript. E.g I don't want to comment out EVERY line of code where it contains a GTM variable, can `prettier` simply recognise that say `{{my_own_variable}}.map()` is the same as `my_own_variable.map()`

Comment: `// prettier-ignore` use this tag on top of the code?

Comment: that would need me comment out every line of code contains a GTM variable, so I want a way that I can simply make `prettier` recognise it instead of ignore it. See my latest edit. Thanks

Comment: In that case you would use override similar to https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#example-configuration but not sure which override is applicable in your case since you are using double curly. Also your question <title> becomes invalid because you dont want to ignore rather incorporate custom tag to be recognized by prettier.

Comment: cheers, I've updated the title now